# MySQL get rows where corresponding row in same table exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get rows from a table according to some basic where clauses, and now I want to include an "AND EXISTS" clause on the end. My code is the following:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT object_id FROM ".
          $db_table_prefix."user_events
          WHERE LPAD(start_timestamp,15,'0') < LPAD(?,15,'0')
          AND event_id = ?
          AND EXISTS ( 
            SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_prefix."user_events
              WHERE LPAD(start_timestamp,15,'0') > LPAD(?,15,'0')
              AND event_id = ? )
        ");
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to specify a column value from the main query within the AND EXISTS subquery.

I'm looking for a way to tack on this bit into the subquery:

```
AND object_id = **object_id from main query**
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, added an alias to the subquery's table to avoid confusion

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT object_id FROM ".
      $db_table_prefix."user_events
      WHERE LPAD(start_timestamp,15,'0') < LPAD(?,15,'0')
      AND event_id = ?
      AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_prefix."user_events AS u
          WHERE LPAD(u.start_timestamp,15,'0') > LPAD(?,15,'0')
          AND u.object_id = " .$db_table_prefix.".object_id
          AND u.event_id = ? )
    ");
```

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't realise you could alias in MySQL :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `EXISTS`, you might find a self-join syntax is clearer here, I cannot deduce exactly what you want from your code, but to get `object_id` for an event that started before a specific time, and was also started again later:

```
SELECT  ue1.object_id 
FROM    user_events ue1 join user_events ue2
WHERE   ue1.event_id = ue2.event_id AND
        ue1.object_id = ue2.object_id AND
        ue1.event_id = ? AND 
        LPAD(ue1.start_timestamp, 15, '0') < LPAD(ue2.start_timestamp, 15, '0') AND 
        LPAD(ue1.start_timestamp, 15, '0') < LPAD(?, 15, '0')
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified further, the second event is actually a different one (with different id) but belonging to same object. I've read that EXISTS can be time-consuming, so I will test your code as well. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

and object_id in (select object_id from ...